# Setting up node oidc-provider with keycloak docker

Tags: docker, keycloak, openid-connect, node-oidc-provider

I am trying to have a basic node oidc-provider app as OIDC provider for my keycloak server.

Keycloak correctly links to the login page of my app. After entering username and password I get correctly transfered back to keycloak.

However, keycloak than says "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider".

---

Identity Provider config:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OG39.png)

---

My app:

```
    import express, { Application } from "express";
    import { ClientMetadata, Provider } from "oidc-provider";
    
    const app: Application = express();
    
    const clients: ClientMetadata[] = [
      {
        client_id: "test_app",
        grant_types: ["authorization_code"],
        client_secret: "secret",
        response_types: ["code"],
        redirect_uris: [
          "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/react-auth/broker/keycloak-oidc/endpoint",
        ],
        token_endpoint_auth_method: "client_secret_post",
      },
    ];
    
    const provider = new Provider("http://localhost:5000", {
      clients: clients,
      pkce: {
        methods: ["plain"],
        required: () => {
          return false;
        },
      },
    });
    app.use("/", provider.callback());
    app.listen(5000, async () => {
      console.log(` Server: Running on port 5000`);
    });
```

---

Trace from keycloak:

```
07:27:14,918 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-10) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=react-auth, clientId=react-auth, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=607b8097-a13c-40eb-8b24-9b97b2cfeef4, authSessionParentId=607b8097-a13c-40eb-8b24-9b97b2cfeef4, authSessionTabId=B_54zaV7b2I

07:36:09,635 ERROR [org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-15) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:5000 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:156)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.makeRequest(SimpleHttp.java:277)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asResponse(SimpleHttp.java:216)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asString(SimpleHttp.java:208)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.0//org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:500)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)

at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)

at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.0//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)

at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.0//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.1.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)

at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)

at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)

at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)

at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)

at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)

at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)

at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)

at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)

at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)

at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)

at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)

at org.apache.httpcomponents.core//org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)

... 92 more


07:36:09,639 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-15) type=IDENTITY_PROVIDER_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=react-auth, clientId=react-auth, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=identity_provider_login_failure, code_id=fc50e8fd-e6c9-440c-809f-aaabd037a0e2, authSessionParentId=fc50e8fd-e6c9-440c-809f-aaabd037a0e2, authSessionTabId=wCCAq2-Ux3A
```

---

> NB: when i test the token endpoint using postman it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling Validate Signatures and Use JWKS URL (shown after enabling validate signatures) and insert the jwk url. It should be http://localhost:5000/jwks